# Write $p \rightarrow \lnot q$ in CNF form with only and ,or and brackets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

Write $p \rightarrow \lnot q$ in CNF form with only and, or, and/or brackets

How on earth would I even do this? Completely lost! Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Recall: $$p\rightarrow \lnot q \equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q$$

The right-hand side is in [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (CNF).

Please take a look at the linked Wikipedia entry and review what *conjunctive normal form* permits (e.g., you don't mention that negated *literals* are permitted (e.g., the literals in this example would be $p$ and $q$) and what it does not allow, as well as some nice examples illustrating statements expressed in conjunctive normal form.